# How to Count the number of times a cell in one column matches a cell in another column?

Tags: excel-formula

I have two columns. Column A is a list of text values. Column B will be individual text values that may or may not match Column A. Across say 20 rows, I want to use something like COUNTIF at the bottom of Column B to count how many answers in Column B match the correct answer in Column A.

For example, if Column A reads:

```
 1. Apple
 2. Orange
 3. Banana
 4. Kumquat
 5. Pineapple
```

Column B reads:

```
 1. Apple
 2. Guava
 3. Pistachio
 4. Kumquat
 5. Pineapple
```

Essentially, rows 1, 4 & 5 all match, thus the sum at the bottom of column B would be 3.

Is there a way to do this with a formula?

Comment: Do they need to match by row or just anywhere in the two?

Comment: You can try inserting a third column with a formula `=IF(A1=B1,"Correct", "Incorrect")`. This formula is for the first row. Copy it down till all the rows that contain data. Then at the end of the second column put the formula `=countif(C:C, "Correct")` and it will give you the number of correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
{=SUM(IF(A1:A5=B1:B5,1,0))}
```

To use this formula, type in any cell "=SUM(IF(A1:A5=B1:B5;1;0))" and press CTRL+SHIFT+INTRO

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5=B1:B5))`